# Neutral geometry: given a triangle $ABC$ and a line $r$, prove that $r$ must intersect at least one of the lines of the triangle

Tags: geometry

This actually came up as a lemma I need to prove something else, but I'm having a hard time with it. Intuitively I know that if $r$ doesn't intersect, say, the line $AB$, then it must intersect $AC$ and $BC$, otherwise, I wouldn't have a triangle, but I haven't been able to prove it.

EDIT: Sorry for not making it clearer, but I can't use coordinates or anything like that here (I haven't defined what it means for two lines to be parallel yet either).

Comment: No, not all lines of a triangle can be parallel. What I want to do is prove that, though.

Comment: So if you can't use coordinates and you can't use the notion of two lines being parallel, perhaps you need to be more explicit about what you *can* use.

Comment: @Malcolm The title of the question already says "neutral geometry". What more do you want?

Comment: I can use all the axioms of neutral geometry and its results (so basically anything that isn't the parallel postulate).

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thank-you.  The sarcasm is appreciated too.

Comment: Another red flag is that the statement is false if the triangle is degenerate (i.e all vertices are colinear).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not be able to prove this, because it's false in hyperbolic geometry. (Of course, it's true in Euclidean geometry, so it's independent from neutral geometry.)

Consider the diagram below (in the Poincaré disk model). If $\triangle ABC$ is formed by the three red lines, then the blue line does not intersect any of them.

[image]